# VSCode does not open the command palette when I run the keyboard shortcut "ctrl+shift+P"

Tags: visual-studio-code, keyboard-shortcuts, shortcut, vscode-keybinding

I have windows 11 and vscode. When I want to open the command palette, I usually press "ctrl_left+shift+p" and it opens. But, with the computer I am currently working with, it does not.

I understand, that it is possible that this is happening because another program has this shortcut linked to it and has higher priority before my vscode.  I have tried closing all the programs that seem to be running but have not been able to figure anything out. I deduce this because the shortcut "ctrl_right+shift+p" does open the command palette.

I have already looked in the "keybindings.json" file and have not been able to find out anything as everything seems to be correct.

Also, I have run the "Developer: Toggle Keyboard Shortcuts Troubleshooting" function and this is the log it generates when launching the keyboard shortcut:

```
2023-03-27 22:11:19.310 [info] [KeybindingService]: / Received  keydown event - modifiers: [ctrl], code: ControlLeft, keyCode: 17, key: Control
2023-03-27 22:11:19.310 [info] [KeybindingService]: | Converted keydown event - modifiers: [ctrl], code: ControlLeft, keyCode: 5 ('Ctrl')
2023-03-27 22:11:19.311 [info] [KeybindingService]: \ Keyboard event cannot be dispatched in keydown phase.
2023-03-27 22:11:19.486 [info] [KeybindingService]: / Received  keydown event - modifiers: [ctrl,shift], code: ShiftLeft, keyCode: 16, key: Shift
2023-03-27 22:11:19.486 [info] [KeybindingService]: | Converted keydown event - modifiers: [ctrl,shift], code: ShiftLeft, keyCode: 4 ('Shift')
2023-03-27 22:11:19.486 [info] [KeybindingService]: \ Keyboard event cannot be dispatched in keydown phase.
2023-03-27 22:11:19.686 [info] [KeybindingService]: + Ignoring single modifier ctrl due to it being pressed together with other keys.
```

Comment: What do you see in the keyboard shortcut editor UI when you search for that keyboard shortcut, and when you search for that command/action (to open the command palette)?

Comment: @user In the interface I can see what my command is linked to the command "Show all commands", but this is with the right ctrl. When I search by command and press "ctrl_left+shift+p" vscode only recognizes "ctrl+shift" but does not recognize the 'P' key.

Comment: @Víctor  Hey did you resolve this? Win 11 has F1 and ctrl + shift + p with default behaviour.. so annoying.

Comment: I did not manage to solve it. Almost certainly some other program, extension or similar was taking the focus of the `CTRL + SHIFT + P` command, but I couldn't find a solution...

Answer (score 0):

I also faced this problem today on Mac, what helped for me was using the site
defkey to see what application uses what shortcut, there i found out that my todo app also used that shortcut.

Maybe you recognise a program that uses that combination.
https://defkey.com/what-means/ctrl-shift-p

The other way, is a bit die-hard, but that is opening VScode and then killing processes within taskmanager, untill the shortcut opens in VScode.